# Explain simple search engine

Tags: web-crawler

Can anybody explain me simple search engine?

What it should look like, what components it should have and how it's working?

There is a web crawler, there is indexing and querying is what I know. What part of it is the most difficult to do?

Where to use pagerank algorithm - in crawling? or in querying i.e. showing the results?
What is indexing?

I read stuff but it's little bit complicated.

What I would like to do is to create simple java search engine. It doesn't matter what algorithm will be used, I have breadth-first so far, I think it is the simpliest algorithm.
I have a simple web crawler, I enter seed url and limit of searched pages.
Firstly crawler checks link, robots.txt and if it can it downloads first page, extract urls from page and adds them to list. When crawler finish extracting urls from first page, it takes first url in list and extract links and so on.

What about indexing?

I really dont understand this part. If I want full-page indexing how should I do that? Simply add full text of downloaded page to database?

Indexing is my most important part to do so please explain this part.

Thanx in advance!

Comment: When you googled "full text indexing", what did you find?  There are usually  a lot of articles on this.  Which ones did you read?  What part confused you?

Comment: Also, how large is your hard disk?

Comment: Mr Lister - I think i don't need large hdd because i need to crawl only pages within one (not very large) domain.

Comment: S.Lott - I didn't read yet about full text indexing, so far i read some articles about search engines and web crawlers. There was mentioned indexing but it was simply described.

Comment: Im reading about indexing right now, and what i read is that page need to be parsed to words. This part i dont understand. I need to parse page to words, and i think, eliminate comments, tags and other unnecessary words? and what then? create table where i would have lets say page_id, url (where word was found), word ??

Comment: -1; Far too many question marks!

Answer (score 0):

The book [Algorithms of the Intelligent Web](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988665) has an excellent introduction to the PageRank algorithm and a nice walk through of implementing it yourself. I suggest you get a copy of this and work through Chapter 2 to get a good understanding of this space.